# QT Charts QML scrolling X axis in ms

Tags: qt, qml

I am trying to display live data in QT Charts QML

I update the Y value with a Timer every 25 milliseconds 
The x axis should show a dynamic 5 seconds window  (current time +- 2500 millisenconds ) How can i make the X axis dynamically show a live updated 5 seconds window  ?

So far i got the timer right which triggers every 25 milliseconds .

I adapted one of the QT examples and so far the live update works .

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtCharts 2.0

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    property double startTime: 0

    ChartView {
        title: startTime
        anchors.fill: parent
        legend.visible: false
        antialiasing: true

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisX
            min: 0
            max: 10
            tickCount: 5
        }

        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY1
            min: -0.5
            max: 1.5
        }
        ValueAxis {
            id: axisY2
            min: 0
            max: 1000
        }

        SplineSeries {
            id: series1
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY1
        }

        SplineSeries {
            id: series2
            axisX: axisX
            axisY: axisY2
        }
    }

    // Add data dynamically to the series
    Timer {
        id: refreshTimer
        interval: 25
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: {
            series1.append(2, Dashboard.gpsSpeed);
            series2.append(10, Dashboard.gpsAltitude);
            console.log ("Timer Triggered");
    }
 }

}
```

Comment: Did I understand you correctly that you want to have your x-axis to be able to scroll dynamically?

Comment: yes exactly that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly you want to have the x-axis scroll dynamically with the current data. So you would need to adjust your min and max property of the corresponding axis.

```
Timer{
    property int amountOfData: 0 //So we know when we need to start scrolling
    id: refreshTimer
    interval: 25
    running: true 
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        series1.append(2, Dashboard.gpsSpeed);
        series2.append(10, Dashboard.gpsAltitude);

        if(amountOfData > axisX.max){
            axisX.min++;
            axisX.max++;
        }else{
            amountOfData++; //This else is just to stop incrementing the variable unnecessarily
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how my code looks now , i also delete the datapoints that are not visible to the user anymore.

```
// Add data dynamically to the series
Timer {
    property int amountOfData: 0 //So we know when we need to start
    property int timeline: 0 // Start of the timeline
    id: refreshTimer
    interval: 50
    running: false
    repeat: true
    onTriggered: {
        timeline++;
        series1.append(timeline, Dashboard.revs);
        series2.append(timeline, Dashboard.speed);

        if(amountOfData > axisX.max){
            axisX.min++;
            axisX.max++;
        }else{
            amountOfData++; //This else is just to stop incrementing the variable unnecessarily
        }
        //remove all data points that are not visible anymore
        if (timeline > 100){
            series1.remove(1);
            series2.remove(1);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the  if (timeline > 100){ series1.remove(1); series2.remove(1);  does also delete data on the screen for some reason . i also tried remove(0) but that also deletes on screen data. Not sure what i am doing wrong here